# How to write data into a macro-enabled Excel file (write.xlslx corrupts my document)?

Tags: r, vba, xlconnect, xlsm, openxlsx

I'm trying to write a table into a macro-enabled Excel file (.xlsm) through the R. The write.xlsx (openxlsx) and writeWorksheetToFile (XLconnect) functions don't work.

When I used the `openxlsx` package, as seen below, the resulting .xlsm files ended up getting corrupted.

Code:

```
library(XLConnect)
library(openxlsx)
for (i in 1:3){
  write.xlsx(Input_Files[[i]], Inputs[i],  sheetName="Input_Sheet")
}

#Input_Files[[i]] are the R data.frames which need to be inserted into the .xslm file
#Inputs[i] are the excel files upon which the tables should be written into
```

Corrupted .xlsm file error message after `write.xlsx`:
*Excel cannot open the file 'xxxxx.xslm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file*

After researching this problem extensively, I found that the `XLConnect` connect package offers the `writeWorksheetToFile` function which works with .xlsm, albeit after running it a few times it yields an error message that there is no more free space. It also runs for 20+ minutes for tables with approximately 10,000 lines. I tried adding `xlcFreeMemory` at the beginning of the for loop, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Code:

```
library(XLConnect)
library(openxlsx)
for (i in 1:3){
  xlcFreeMemory()
  writeWorksheetToFile(Inputs[i], Input_Files[[i]], "Input_Sheet")
}

#Input_Files[[i]] are the R data.frames which need to be inserted into the .xslm file
#Inputs[i] are the excel files upon which the tables should be written into
```

Could anyone recommend a way to easily and quickly transfer an R table into an xlsm file without corrupting it?